# How do I ensure D3 finishes loading several CSVs before javascript runs?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm loading a CSV of a list of *other* CSV files into javascript using D3.

When I run the following code, the employees array is still empty by the time it gets to it in the code. Is there a correct way to ensure that D3 finishes loading the data before the javascript continues?

```
var employees = [];

//Retrieve the file list of all the csvs in the data directory, then run a callback on them
function retrieveList(url,callback) {
    d3.csv(url,function(data) {
        callback(data);
    })
}

//Parse a file list, and then update the employee array with the data within
function parseList(filenames){
    filenames.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.csv(d.filename,function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) employees.push(d.name));
        }
    }
}

//Run this code
var filenamesUrl = "http://.../filenames.csv"
retrieveList(filenamesUrl, parseList);

console.log(employees); //This logs "[]"
```

If I load the page in Chrome, when I go into console and log employees, sure enough it returns the array filled with names. How can I make that the case by the time I run console.log(employees) on the last line?

Comment: If you'd like to see more clearly what I'm trying to do, it's here: https://github.com/mkwng/d3-experiments/

Answer (score 21):

You could use [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) to collect the results from all the d3.csv calls:

```
function parseList(filenames){
  var q = queue();
  filenames.forEach(function(d) {
    //add your csv call to the queue
    q.defer(function(callback) {
      d3.csv(d.filename,function(res) { callback(null, res) });
    });
  });

  q.await(restOfCode)
}    

function restOfCode(err, results) {
  //results is an array of each of your csv results
  console.log(results)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. It's just that you're logging `employees` before the data is ready. But if you `console.log` it on the last line of `parseList` you should have it.