# jQuery Promises not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have 2 csv's that I'm trying to read in, after which I use the data in those two to do stuff:

```
function getData() {

  var deferredObject = $.Deferred(); //representation of some asynchronous work 
  d3.csv("./parse_shp.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    shp_array = data;
  });

  d3.csv("./fao_coutnry_shp.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    fao_array = data;
  });

  //once both of those are done, resolve the promise 
  deferredObject.resolve();

  return deferredObject.promise();
}

function LevenshteinDistance() {
  console.log("do stuff with the data");
}

//call LevenDistance after the promise has been resolved 
getData().then(LevensteinDistance());
```

But that's not working... it'll print the line `"do something with the data"` before printing the data of the csv's.

What am I doing wrong? I used [this](http://www.vasanthk.com/jquery-promises-and-deferred-objects/) link as an example.

I don't understand how connect `deferredObject` and `getData()`?  Because even if I create the deferred object in the function, won't it just asynchronously do the csv reads anyway and then erroneously call `defferedObject.resolve()`?

Anyway, I'm new to promises so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you are resolving the promise before either of the .csv methods have completed.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks! So how would I resolve it after they have completed? Do I have to bind a promise to the csv methods themselves?

Comment: `getData().then(LevensteinDistance());` is a bug, you should not CALL LevensteinDistance and pass its return value to `then`, you should just pass `LevensteinDistance` (the function) without `()` after it

Comment: @PJSCopeland you should verify with the OP before making substantial changes to the code of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `.then()` must be a function. You're *calling* the function immediately, because you have `()` after the function name. It should be:

```
getData().then(LevenshteinDistance);
```

Comment: OP is also *resolving* the deferred immediately instead of after the 2 d3 callbacks are done.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, but I'm not familiar enough with d3.js to know how to fix it. Does `d3.csv()` return a promise?

Comment: That's one of my problems, thanks! I guess.. my question is then how would I resolve the deferred objects after the 2 d3 callbacks are done? Would I have to have a promise for each of the csv methods?

Comment: I think that's what's needed, but I'm not sure how to code it. It's possible that `d3.csv()` returns a promise, but I couldn't find that in the API documentation.

Comment: Looks like you can simply [promisify the callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572).

Comment: Wrapping it in a Promise.resolve would force it to return it's value/error as a resolved/rejected promise or just return the promise if it was one.  Promise.resolve(d3.csv())

Comment: @Dtipson: It would not be "forced" to do anything. It's just as likely that it returns `undefined`, and then you'd have a promise for that value.

Comment: Thanks! I'll found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425987/how-do-i-ensure-d3-finishes-loading-several-csvs-before-javascript-runs) so i'll try that first, but if not, i'll look at the other link, thanks!

Comment: Bergi, all I meant is that if it returned a value or a thenable, wrapping it in Promise.resolve would make it consistently return a Promise.  I didn't mean to imply that it would magically handle functions that don't return anything. It looks like d3.csv currently uses callbacks though: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV